# Fix Squid: Your cache is running out of filedescriptors error

Tags: 20.04, squid

Running Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest version of Squid Proxy

I followed this article: [When building a proxy server on ubuntu, please tell me about the parameters that need to be tuned in relation to the OS system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450873/when-building-a-proxy-server-on-ubuntu-please-tell-me-about-the-parameters-that)

But there is no such directory on step 4. Edit the squid system configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/squid
```

All other directories are present. Thanks in advance